# Android, Facebook login doesn't work when the Facebook application is installed

Tags: android, facebook

I'm developing an application that should be connect with facebook, I followed the facebook tutorial and insert the hash key too in the facebook dashboard.

I was able to connect with facebook but when install the facebook application I can't connect anymore with facebook, the session state is closed.

I read several topics but I can't find a solution that is good for my problem,
so I have decide to post my question, do you have any idea regard my issue?

Following my source code

```
public class FragmentSn extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "FragmentSn";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper; 
static boolean fbLoggedIn;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentsn, container, false);

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email"));
    authButton.setFragment(this);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new  
    FacebookDialog.Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, 
        Bundle data) {
            Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        fbLoggedIn=true;
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        fbLoggedIn=false;
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity sourcecode

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

// Declare Tab Variable
ActionBar.Tab Tab1, Tab2, Tab3,Tab4;
Fragment fragmentMap = new FragmentMap();
Fragment fragmentCoupon = new FragmentCoupon();
Fragment fragmentCampaign = new FragmentCampaign();
Fragment fragmentSn = new FragmentSn();
Tools tools;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    // Hide Actionbar Icon
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    // Hide Actionbar Title
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Create Actionbar Tabs
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set Tab Icon and Titles
    Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_map));
    Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_coupon));
    Tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_campaign));
    //Tab4 = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_sn));

    // Set Tab Listeners
    Tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentMap));
    Tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentCoupon));
    Tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentCampaign));
    //Tab4.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentSn));

    // Add tabs to actionbar
    actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab3);
    //actionBar.addTab(Tab4);

    // Facebook - START
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        fragmentSn = new FragmentSn();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, fragmentSn)
        .commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        fragmentSn = (FragmentSn) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
    // Facebook - END

    // AM 2014/01/15 - START 
    //Check update information 
    tools = new Tools(this.getApplicationContext());
    // AM 2014/01/15 - END

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

}
```

look forward your reply,
thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/ match your hash key with given code to generate hash key programmactily are same or not

Comment: thanks chintan for your reply, but unfortunately I checked the hask key more times and it match.

Comment: there is default example of login , just download latest sdk and try with it.

Comment: I did it, I use the latest facebook sdk.
I'm able to login with facebook if the facebook application is not installed in the device.
Furthermore, when I run my application in debug, any message are not showing.
I also think that the problem is the key hashes but i checked it several times and it is correct.
I don't understand where is the error

Comment: post your MainActivity extends FragmentActivity code

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have updated my post with mainactivity source code.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this before too and recreating the debug key resolved this issue for me. Note you can add multiple keys on the Facebook app profile, you will probably want to add at least the debug key from all development machines and the release key.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but after recreate the key ashes in the same way that I did until now and insert in the facebook dashboard the program start to receive correctly the information by facebook application.

Thanks chintak khetiya for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the emulator? If so, try the ARM version. Facebook LoginActivity crashes on the Intel emulator.